# I have trouble installing a library with cabal

Tags: haskell, cabal

What I want to install is [`scalpel`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/scalpel) library.

When I try:

```
cabal install -p scalpel
```

I have following output:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600]
(c) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\maion_000>cabal install -p scalpel
Resolving dependencies...
In order, the following would be installed:
curl-1.3.8 +new-base (new package)
regex-base-0.93.2 (reinstall) changes: bytestring-0.10.0.2 -> 0.10.6.0,
mtl-2.1.2 -> 2.2.1
regex-tdfa-1.2.2 (new package)
tagsoup-0.13.10 (new package)
scalpel-0.3.0.1 (new package)
cabal: The following packages are likely to be broken by the reinstalls:
regex-posix-0.95.2
regex-compat-0.95.1
haskell-platform-2013.2.0.0
Use --force-reinstalls if you want to install anyway.
```

What should I do? I tried --force-reinstalls and it gives more errors.

Comment: it would be best to switch to using [`stack`](http://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/README/) or [`cabal sandboxes`](http://coldwa.st/e/blog/2013-08-20-Cabal-sandbox.html) - maybe you need to delete the current .cabal folder

Comment: `scalpel` is on stackage https://www.stackage.org/nightly-2016-05-08/package/scalpel-0.3.0.1 ; if you learn how to install with `stack` you won't have to deal with this sort of problem.

Comment: It looks like you're using a haskell platform from 2013? That ships with ghc 7.6.2 -- lots of packages consider that at the tail end of their support window. It would be much better to use a more up to date ghc regardless. Having done so, if you stick with cabal, you may want to consider using sandboxes to prevent issues like this in the future...

Answer (score 1):

Cabal can become *very* [problematic](https://wiki.haskell.org/Cabal/Survival) with dependencies blocking each other.

If you can, use [`stack`](http://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/README/) or [`cabal sandbox`](http://coldwa.st/e/blog/2013-08-20-Cabal-sandbox.html).
This isolates creates isolated environments that can prevent the 'dependency hell'.

`stack` automaticall creates a new sandbox for each project, while `cabal sandbox` has to be triggered manually.

You can try to delete `.cabal` and maybe `.ghc` from your home directory to fix the current situation, but that fix will be temporary if you do not use sandboxing (which is exactly what `stack` or `cabal sandbox` do)